# Could there be an option to turn the duck into a pot plant?

Tags: feature-request, fun, april-fools, quack-overflow

In my culture, the preferred metaphor for something whose function is simply to be a passive recipient of your utterances is a 'pot plant'. I am uncomfortable talking to the duck.

Could there be an option to change it to a pot plant?

Comment: The _rubber duck_ is a **widespread** metaphor in IT development.

Comment: It's okay, the duck seems to be uncomfortable speaking to us in return :-(.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ FWIW, I was first quacked at on Music.SE...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a plant in a pot, not a plant of pot? At least to me, the title suggests the latter.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think the latter is a "nice to have", but not necessary for the minimum viable product.

Comment: But.. how will a plant respond?

Comment: @SurajRao Ask rene :-P ...

Comment: The Aspidistra would be appropriate, as they have been known to talk back.

Comment: Not sure the bowl of petunias would be as helpful as it really only understands gravity.

Comment: I usually explain my problem to my dog... https://i.imgur.com/fAJSbYo.png

Comment: Could we get this implemented by 4/20?

Comment: Would it be okay to turn it into a [Level 1 Potted Plant](http://logicishard.blogspot.com/2012/12/munchkin.html)?  Either way you avoid the Duck of Doom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great idea!

[image]

I’m sure that’ll be more comfortable for everyone.

Comment: That's exactly how the duck makes me feel. That thing is scary. It's not funny.

Comment: @Bread: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSx3U.png

Comment: You shall be hanged for you have made the duck sad.

Comment: I think it's actually a good idea to be able to change it in a plant. There are cultural differences.