# Can you make the rubber duck look like a paperclip?

Tags: feature-request, april-fools, quack-overflow

What if I prefer to see a helpful paperclip instead of a duck?

At least on Writing.SE. Most users would likely be delighted.

Comment: _"Most users would likely be delighted."_ Sure??!?

Comment: The joke is about [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). How would a paperclip get that across?

Comment: @RobertLongson, on Writing.SE the concept of rubber duck debugging is most likely foreign to the users anyway.

Comment: If you have your own website, you can do that there using [this](https://www.smore.com/clippy-js).

Comment: You have Cortana for that @Eddie

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81271/222298 (paperclip, from before the duck appeared) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308587/222298 (potted plant). Ask if you can turn it to Jon Skeet's face next.

Answer (score 17):

There's no need for that.

*It's already Clippy in disguise!*

[image: Ducklippy!]

Comment: Ah, no! My eyes! The PAIN!

Answer (score 16):

Sure, just open the browser's console and type the following:

```
var img = $("<img />").attr("id", "clippy").attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7VoQ.png").css("height", "70px");
$(".js-quack-btn").hide();
$(".quackoverflow").append(img);
```

Preview:

> [image: clippy is here]

Enjoy!

Answer (score 11):

No.

Seriously, No.

Comment: https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/team/Nick%20Craver.gif

Answer (score 11):

That was the original design. Unfortunately we [modeled that idea](http://www.decisionproblem.com/paperclips/) and we found it would [destroy humanity](https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Paperclip_maximizer).