# I have Anatidaephobia - can we change the duck as it is always watching me?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, quack-overflow

Related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308593/can-you-make-the-rubber-duck-look-like-a-paperclip), is there an option to change the duck to something like a large purple Gorilla? I suffer from Anatidaephobia and it is realized when the duck is actually there, watching, always watching.

No, stop, please, I didn't mean to spill my water. No, please, stop looking at me like that.
I know! I know!
I'm a bad coder! Stop reminding me! IT WASN'T MY FAULT THAT I FORGOT CASE-SENSITIVITY!

I'll never do it again, coding duck, I promise, VBA is never a solution to anything.

Comment: The duck has flown away.. You will never hear the _quack_ again

Comment: Hahah considering that the duck is not present anymore, thats funny xD

Answer (score 14):

The duck's been gone for days. If you're still seeing the duck... erm, I'd be a little worried.

Comment: The duck is [watching, always watching](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anatidaephobia), that is my fear